# How to hide the (-) sign from facet filter block?

Tags: 7, search

I am displaying faceted blocks and current search block on the search page.

When I select a filter from any faceted block, it appears in the current search block and also in that faceted block with this sign `(-)`.

When I click on this sign it removes the filter from the search.

It is fine in current search block. But It should not appear in the faceted block.

Suppose If I select `category1` from the facet block. In the current search block and in its facet block it appears like this `(-) category1`.

And I want that in the current search block it should appear like `(-) category1` and in its facet block it should on display its name like `category1` without the `(-)` sign.

Any one who know how to hide this in the facet block?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of theme functions you can use to work with the display of these filters.

[theme_facetapi_deactivate_widget($variables)](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!facetapi!facetapi.theme.inc/function/theme_facetapi_deactivate_widget/7)

[theme_facetapi_link_active($variables)](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!facetapi!facetapi.theme.inc/function/theme_facetapi_link_active/7)

In your case, you could place the following in your theme's template.php file to edit the display of the deactivation 'button' of your facet:

```
function THEME_facetapi_deactivate_widget($variables) {
  return '';
}
```